# sid naming conventions forcontainer and plugins

Tags: naming, oracle12c, sid

With the architecture change in oracle 12, specifically containers and pluggable databases should, should sid naming conventions be changes to help  identify db as container or plugin or which plugins go with which containers. Suggestions and advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You only have an sid per container database and not per pluggable database. Nothing changed in that respect. To connect to pluggable database you have to use services.